# PHP with PDO: Return the correct types from the DB

Tags: php, pdo

I'm using this code (simplified):

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM products');
$products = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($products);
```

And I'm fetching this from a React App. It works, however, the numbers and booleans are all strings. Is there any way to fix this without having to cast the types on the UI everytime?

I'm talking PHP here. I have no access to the PHP config so I'm looking for an all-code solution, if there's any.

Comment: Maybe you can use `CAST(col AS INTEGER)` ?

Comment: You could use `PDO::FETCH_OBJECT` to receive an object instead. You also could create a products class with typed properties (PHP 8) and then use `PDO::FETCH_CLASS`.

Comment: Just disable emulation mode

Comment: @MarkusZeller Wouldn't that still result in the same outcome?

Comment: @Dharman The driver casts the properties when typed and fetches as class.